# GridDB username, password and OS is not set

Tags: operating-system, nodes, cluster-computing, griddb

I have a `GridDB` cluster with only one node in it and I want to add node to the existing cluster. The following command adds a new node to the existing cluster

```
setnode node2 192.168.0.5 10044
```

While executing the above command I am getting an error as follows:

> The username and password and OS user gsadm password is not set. Set them by setuser sub command

The following screenshot shows the error:
[image: error screenshot]

While installing `GridDB` gsadm is registered as an OS to use GridDB, so there must not be an issue with the OS. I have also set a password during the installation, However I used a command

```
ospassword
```

in `gs_admin` to reset the password many times but it didn’t helped in my case and still getting the same error.